# SQL inner joining to left joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

So this might be more of a theoretical question about how joins in MySQL work, but I'd love some guidance.

Let's say I have three tables, table a, b and c, where table a and b are fact tables and table c is table b's dimension table.  If I want to left join table b to table a (I want to keep all of the contents of table a, but also want matching contents in table b), can I still inner join table c to table b even table b is left joined?  Or do I have to left join table c to table b? Or would both of these for all intents and purposes produce the same result?

```
select a.column, c.name
from tablea a
left join tableb b on a.id = b.id
inner join (?) tablec c on b.name_id = c.name
```

Comment: That join kills left join.   If you put b in a where is would also kill the left.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

MySQL supports syntax that allows you to achieve what you want:

```
select a.column, c.name
from
  tablea a
  left join
    tableb b
    inner join tablec c on b.name_id = c.name
   on a.id = b.id
;
```

In this case tables `tableb` and `tablec` are joined first, then the result of their join is outer-joined to `tablea`.

The final result set, however, would be same as with [@simon at rcl's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28590798/297408).

Answer (score 6):

In this case if there is no tablec entry for a tableb, then the whole join will fail and the tablea row will not be included. To include the tablsa entry you would need to make the join to tablc a left join:

```
select a.column, c.name
from tablea a
left join tableb b on a.id = b.id
left join tablec c on b.name_id = c.name
```

That will get you every tablea row even when there is no matching tableb row, and also every tablea and tableb when there is no tablec row.

Answer (score 5):

As far as SQL goes, join order is irrelevent (with the exception of any order that's implied by the join criteria). Something like

```
select *
from      t1
left join t2 on t2.t1_id = t1.id
join      t3 on t3.id    = t1.t3_id
```

is exactly the same as

```
select *
from      t1
join      t3 on t3.id    = t1.t3_id
left join t2 on t2.t1_id = t1.id
```

Here's the conceptual model of how a `select` query works. Once should note, of course, that nothing but the most trivial of SQL implementations would ever actually do this due to the performance implications implied by step #1. However, the results will be as if you went through the steps below.

1. Construct the cartesian product of all tables specified in the `from` clause. This is your candidate result set.
2. Apply the join criteria to eliminate rows from the candidate result set.
3. Apply the criteria specified in the `where` clause to further narrow the result set.

   **Note:** the distinction made in steps two and three can change the result set, depending on whether a particular test is placed in the `where` clause or the `join` criteria. It's not an issue with inner joins, but with outer joins, the location of the test can materially alter the results. Don't ask me how I know this.
4. Apply the criteria specified in the `group by` clause (if any) to partition the result set into groups.
5. For each group, compute the value of any aggregate function specified.
6. Collapse each group into a single row consisting of its key values (from the `group by` clause) and the values of its aggregate functions.
7. Further winnow the result set down by applying the criteria specified in the `having` clause (if any).
8. At this point, you have the final result set. Order it according to the criteria specified in the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers worked for me.

I used the Answer from Gajus here : [Using left join and inner join in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685289/using-left-join-and-inner-join-in-the-same-query)

> SELECT *
> FROM foo f1
> LEFT JOIN (bar b1
> INNER JOIN baz b2 ON b2.id = b1.baz_id
> ) ON
> b1.id = f1.bar_id