# Select and join returning duplicate data

Tags: sql

I have some tables that can be accessed [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/229b87b/2) and I would like to get a new table with EntryId from Entry table and ProtocolNumber from JudicialOrder table. For that I'm using this query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ET.EntryId, JOA.ProtocolNumber FROM Entry AS ET
LEFT JOIN JudicialOrderAccount AS JOT ON JOT.AccountId = ET.OwnerAccountId
INNER JOIN JudicialOrder AS JOA ON JOA.JudicialOrderId = JOT.JudicialOrderId;
```

But the ProtocolNumber is duplicated, what could be wrong with my query?

Comment: select distinct gives you distinct combinations of EntryId and ProtocolNumber.  If the same ProtocolNumber is associated with multiple EntryId, you will have duplicate ProtocolNumber in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

As Kurt said only the combination of ET.EntryId, JOA.ProtocolNumber is unique. You will recognize it if you add an order by.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ET.EntryId, JOA.ProtocolNumber FROM Entry AS ET
LEFT JOIN JudicialOrderAccount AS JOT ON JOT.AccountId = ET.OwnerAccountId
INNER JOIN JudicialOrder AS JOA ON JOA.JudicialOrderId = JOT.JudicialOrderId
ORDER BY ET.EntryId, JOA.ProtocolNumber;
```

If you would really like to have unique protocol number you would need to group by ProtocolNumber and wrap EntryId in some string_agg function (depends on your database).

FYI: Your LEFT JOIN - INNER JOIN combination ends up being **two INNER JOINs**, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9685289/15709597)